# Finding words that start with user entered letter

Tags: c++

I've managed to get the count of the user entered character in  any place of the string, but how would I get count of only the words that start with the user entered character?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string main;
    char charr;

    cout << "Enter the main string : "<<endl;
    getline(cin,main);
    cout << "Enter a character: "<<endl;
    cin >> charr;
    
    
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < main.size(); i++)
        if (main[i] == charr)
         count++;
    
    cout << count << endl;
   

}
```

Comment: I would like to count the words starting with charr.

Comment: Do you get any errors from using `main` as a function and `main` as a variable?  I recommend using less confusing names, like "main_string" and "user_char".

Comment: I recommend using a constant temporary variable to hold the result of `main.size()`.  No need to recalculate the size of the `main` string in each iteration.

Answer (score 2):

You could put the `std::string` in a [`std::istringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) and then [`std::count_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count) the words starting with the entered character.

It could look like this:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string main;
    char charr;

    std::cout << "Enter the main string:\n";
    std::getline(std::cin, main);
    std::cout << "Enter a character:\n";
    if(not (std::cin >> charr)) return 1;

    std::istringstream is(main); // put the main string in an istringstream

    // count words starting with charr:
    auto count = std::count_if(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(is),
                               std::istream_iterator<std::string>{},
                               [charr](const std::string& word) {
                                   return word.front() == charr;
                               });

    std::cout << count << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your example, you fail to ensure the character before the one being checked is whitespace. Doing that and your approach will work. You don't want to know how many characters there are that match `charr`, you want to know how many words *start with* `charr`. To calculate that from the entire `std::string`, you need to check that the previous character is whitespace.

You can easily check whether the previous character is whitespace by including `cctype` and using the `isspace()` macro.

Additionally, you must validate EVERY user-input. The user may generate a manual `EOF` to cancel input which is a valid user-action. (<kbd>Ctrl + d</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl + z</kbd> on windows).

A short example using your read with `getline()`, removing `using namespace std;` and choosing a new name for your string (`line` instead of `main`) would be:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

int main()
{
    std::string line {};
    char charr = 0;
    int count = 0, last = 0;

    std::cout << "Enter the main string : ";
    /* validate read and line not empty */
    if (!getline(std::cin, line) || line.size() == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    std::cout << "Enter a character: ";
    if (!(std::cin >> charr)) {                     /* validate read */
        return 0;
    }
    
    if (line[0] == charr) {                         /* check 1st char */
        count++;                                    /* increment on match */
    }
    last = line[0];                                 /* set last char seen */
    
    for (size_t i = 1; i < line.size(); i++) {      /* loop 1 to end */
        /* last is space and current is charr */
        if (isspace(last) && line[i] == charr) {
            count++;                                /* increment count */
        }
        last = line[i];                             /* set last char seen */
    }
    std::cout << count << '\n';                     /* output results */
}
```

(**note:** while `using namespace std;` may be fine and convenient for small example programs, see: [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/364696))

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/startswith
Enter the main string : my dog has fleas and my cat has none
Enter a character: h
2
```

Or

```
$ ./bin/startswith
Enter the main string : my dog has fleas and my cat has none
Enter a character: n
1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << main;
string word;
while(ss >> word)
{
  if(word[0] == charr)
    ++count;
}
```

EDIT: correction using comment of Ted Lyngmo. Thanks.